# How to improve 2 million data query speed in Django RESTful APIs

Tags: django, mongodb, database-performance

I have a scientific research publications data of 2 Million records. I used django restframework to write apis for searching the data in `title` and `abstract`. This is taking me `12 seconds` while using `postgres` as db, but if I used `MongoDB` as db, it goes down to `6seconds`.

But even 6 seconds sounds a lot of waiting for user to me. I indexed the `title` and `abstract`, but abstract indexing failed because some of the abstract texts are too lengthy.

Here is the django Model using MongoDB(MongoEngine as ODM):

```
class Journal(Document):
    title = StringField()
    journal_title = StringField()
    abstract = StringField()
    full_text = StringField()
    pub_year = IntField()
    pub_date = DateTimeField()
    pmid = IntField()
    link = StringField()
```

How do I improve the query performance, what stack makes the search and retrieval more faster?.

Comment: This is way too broad as it is. There can be numerous possibilities depending on your queries, on your indexes, on your hardware, on possible search backends, on full-text search, etc etc.

Comment: sure. but thats the problem I am facing. Could your suggest me a better way to solve this or any suggestions are welcome to simplify the question. To answer your quick questions : im using full-text search too, on a Mac Pro hardware. I tested with both postgres and MongoDB as database. Please tell me , what more info you'd like to know to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Some pointers about optimisation for the Django ORM with Postgres:

- Use `db_index=True` on fields that will be search upon often and have some degree of repetition between entries, like "title".
- Use `values()` and `values_list()` to select only the columns you want from a QuerySet.
- If you're doing full text search in any of those columns (like a `contains` query), bear in mind that Django has support for [full text search directly on a Postgres database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).
- Use `print queryset.query` to check what kind of SQL query is going into your database and if it can be improved upon.
- Many Postgres optimisation techniques rely in custom SQL queries that can be made in Django by using `RawSQL` expressions.
- Remember that there are many, many ways to search for data in a database, be it relational or not-relational in nature. In your case, MongoDB is not "faster" than Postgres, it's just doing a better job at querying what you really want.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I'm not in favour of MongoDB over Postrges. When I tried both, I saw good results with MongoDB, thats it. I did the indexing with `db_index=True` and also using   `values()` to make the retrieval light, I even removed the 'count' which uses `queryset.count()` in API that is performance heavy. Let me try whats happening using `queryset.query` .I wil update once I try them all

Comment: Did you find MongoDB was still faster?